# Tiltfile: iterate over directory

Tags: kubernetes, bazel

All my kustomize declarations for my kubernetes cluster are stored in a folder with this structure:

```
.  
├── apps  
│   └── nginx-test  
│       ├── base  
│       │   ├── deployment.yaml  
│       │   ├── ingress.yaml  
│       │   ├── kustomization.yaml  
│       │   ├── namespace.yaml  
│       │   └── service.yaml  
│       ├── dev  
│       │   ├── ingress.yaml  
│       │   └── kustomization.yaml  
│       └── tollana  
│           ├── ingress.yaml  
│           └── kustomization.yaml  
├── infra  
│   ├── cert-manager  
│   │   ├── base  
│   │   │   ├── helmChart.yaml  
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml  
│   │   │   ├── namespace.yaml  
│   │   │   └── values.yaml  
│   │   ├── dev  
│   │   │   └── kustomization.yaml  
│   │   └── tollana  
│   │       └── kustomization.yaml  
│   ├── enroute  
│   │   ├── base  
│   │   │   ├── helmChart.yaml  
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml  
│   │   │   ├── namespace.yaml  
│   │   │   └── values.yaml  
│   │   ├── dev  
│   │   │   ├── add-namespace.yaml  
│   │   │   ├── externalIP.yaml  
│   │   │   └── kustomization.yaml  
│   │   └── tollana  
│   │       ├── add-namespace.yaml  
│   │       ├── externalIP.yaml  
│   │       └── kustomization.yaml
```

I want to have tilt to sync all kustomizations in the dev directories. So far I got this:

```
baseFolders = ["./apps", "./infra"]
for folder in baseFolders:
    appFolders = listdir(folder)
    for appFolder in appFolders:
        if os.path.exists("kubectl kustomize --enable-helm {}/dev/kustomization.yaml").format(os.path.join(folder, appFolder)):
            k8s_yaml(local("kubectl kustomize --enable-helm {}/dev").format(os.path.join(folder, appFolder)))
```

But `listdir("directory")` only lists the files in *directory*.
Is there a way to get all folders in a specific directory?

`os.listdir()` doesn't work:

```
Error: module has no .listdir field or method
```

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have a solution? Even chatgpt can't get it right:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is not supported (yet). There is an open issue for it: https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt/issues/5268